# Handling urls of assets compiled by Rails's assets pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm using an external plugin in my rails project. I've placed the css for it inside `vendor/assets/styles/pluginName`, and the js in `vendor/assets/scripts/pluginName`. I've added `vendor/assets` to `config.assets.path` in `application.rb`, and I'm `require`ing the stylesheet and js file for the plugin in `application.js` and `application.css`

My question is, `vendor/assets/styles/pluginName/styles.css` refers to an image `foo.png` which is located at `vendor/assets/styles/pluginName/foo.png`. When the assets are pre-compiled, does `foo.png` remain at the same path, or do i need to do something so the paths don't break?

Reason for asking: Currently, everything works on localhost, but when i deploy and recompile the assets, the plugin's js seems to work, but the images are missing.